# Error while trying to scrape download links with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape all download links from a website. I have a list with  links but i'm getting error.

list is like this:

```
[<a href='example.com/one'>, <a href='example.com/two'>, <a href='example.com/three'>]
```

when i try to print links only I'm able to do that.

```
for x in range(len(content)):
    print(content[x])
```

but when i try to execute this it doesn't works.

```
for x in range(len(content)):
    content[x] = url + content[x]['href']
    v = s.get(content[x], headers=headers)
    content = BeautifulSoup(v.content, 'lxml')
    temp = content.find_all('a', {'class':'download-link'})
    print(temp[2]['href'])
```

```
  File "app.py", line 31, in <module>
    content[x] = url + content[x]['href']
  File "C:\Users\dead\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1016, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the value of content during your loop, and the new value is not a list with len(new_content)==len(content). I'm not sure why you are updating content, but you should either stop it or update it properly, like:

```
for x in range(len(content)):
    content[x] = url + content[x]['href']
    v = s.get(content[x], headers=headers)
    content = BeautifulSoup(v.content, 'lxml')
    content = content.find_all('a', {'class':'download-link'})
    print(content[2]['href'])
```

Or:

```
for x in range(len(content)):
    content[x] = url + content[x]['href']
    v = s.get(content[x], headers=headers)
```